# How to securely add a password for an existing user in the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, security, mongoose

#### Description

In our database, we have a collection (`customers`) for all ordering customer.
In this collection, we stored all customer's info, including email.
**But without password** since we didn't implement authentication yet.
It looks something like this:

```js
{
  name: "Moaaz Bhnas",
  email: "moaaz@gmail.com",
  ... // other data about the user
}
```

Then we decided to add a sign up form with email and password fields.

#### Problem

When a customer who has a document in our database tries to sign up using the same email.

#### Solution I tried

If a customer in our database tries to sign up with the same email, I only update the password in his/her document:

```
const updatedCustomer = await CustomerModel.updateOne({ email }, {password: newPassword});
```

It worked, but there's a security issue with this solution. Anyone could easily hack a customer if he knows his/her email by just signing up using that email.

#### Question

Is there a secure way to add a password to an existing document with only email?

Comment: why don't you set a dummy password for all customers (who didn't have a password),
then when they will unable to login and you need to set forget password so they will change it themself.

Comment: you can use email verification 
create a link to update the password and send it to the mail then the customer needs to click that link and update password.

Comment: @Moaaz you said "*Anyone could easily hack a customer if he knows his/her email by just signing up using that email*" but the fact is that they are not even protected in the first place, in your current setup it's like they are already hacked, so it can work and you should hope no other user tries to guess a random user's e-mail and change theirs password. The second way is as the above comment says to **INSERT** a randomized password to all of the users which would technically lock their accounts and they'll have to reset their password by a mail link sent to their email.